# What is the difference between Security Token Service and OAuth 2.0 "Authorization Server" role?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, wif

I need to implement OAuth 2.0 protocol and I am thinking about "Authorization Server" part. Can I implement it as a custom Security Token Service (based on WIF classes)?

Answer (score 0):

No, the WIF classes don't support the OAuth2 framework. Writing one from scratch is not trivial. The Thinktecture AuthorizationServer is an open source OAuth2 implementation that might get you started:

http://thinktecture.github.io/Thinktecture.AuthorizationServer/

Comment: Your link is broken Brock :-)